# Select option style change on submit when using "required" with Angular JS

Tags: css, validation, angularjs, required

Why do select option form elements change style when the form is submitted?

```
HTML:
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <form name="test" ng-submit="formSubmit()">
        <select name="selectFormItem" ng-options="selectFormItemValue.value as selectFormItemValue.text for selectFormItemValue in selectFormItemValues" ng-required="true" ng-model="testModel" class="selectStyle">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
        <button id="testSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <br/><br/>
    <span>{{selectFormItemValues}}</span>
    <br/><br/>
</div>

JS:
    function TestController($scope) {
        $scope.selectFormItemValues = [{'value':0, 'text':'value0'}, {'value':1, 'text':'value1'}];

        $scope.formSubmit = function formSubmit() {
            alert("dummySubmit!");
        }
    }

CSS:
body {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;   
}
.selectStyle {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nEzpS/22/

I noticed it happens when "required" is set on select form member.

EDIT:
Tested in Chrome versions: 23.0.1271.97, 24.0.1312.52

Comment: uhhhhh what browser are you in?

Comment: Not seeing the font change to Times with Opera or Firefox, but I do see it in Chrome.  Sounds like a browser bug to me.

Comment: I am using Chrome 23.0.1271.97

Comment: chrome 23.0.1271.101 here and no issues. Also on your JSFiddle you might want to add `http://` in your resources to load bootstrap properly.

Comment: I've updated resources. I'll try with Chrome update also, tnx.

Comment: The bug still exists in Chrome 24beta on Windows. The font changes from Arial to Times New Roman.

Comment: @cimmanon, please consider posting your comment as an answer, so that this question no longer appears on the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with certain versions of Chrome, since the issue does not present in other browsers.