# Font get changed on HTML5 validation in chrome

Tags: css, html

I am having a strange issue with HTML5 validation.

See this fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VNDBq/1/)

When I submit this form without selecting any option, it result into an validation error (which is an expected behavior), but with this the fonts of the dropdown gets changed (notice the `g` in nights).

This behavior is only visible in Google chrome, it worked fine in Mozilla.

I want them to be same after validation also.

Comment: i tried in Chrome 23.0 and did not see the issue.

Comment: @thescientist Well, it is visible here at myside. I am using `Google Chrome Version 23.0.1271.97`

Comment: Are saying an extra g gets added to the dropdown values after an invalid submit?  How specifically?  nightsg?  nigghts?

Comment: well, this is due to chrome

Comment: No, not an extra `g`. I have mentioned `g` just to show that the font changed. In current text `g` shows the most change.

Comment: @AspiringAqib So what can be the possible solution to this?

Comment: @Ravi buddy this is default by google chrome, you have to edit chrome to change that well! i tried my best to use css to not to change it, but this can't be changed! :( still working to get it fixed

Comment: @AspiringAqib There will be someway to change it, I guess.

Comment: instead of using that can't you use js or jQuery?

Comment: This came up on SO a couple days ago:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007767/select-option-style-change-on-submit-when-using-required-with-angular-js

Comment: @cimmanon there, people also saying chrome bug!

Comment: @cimmanon Thanks for the link... But is there any solution to it?

Comment: hey @Ravi can't u use js? to stop user to validate form without selecting a option!

Comment: thats a browser default!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in browser details.
That was the Chromes default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

How are you defining your font? There was a bug in chrome at one point where it wouldn't parse the font family properly unless the primary is defined in 'quotes' ie: font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;

Comment: there is no problem with defining of fonts